# Background images are crisp when repeated, blurry otherwise

Tags: css, image, background

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kCBDH/2/)

I have 3 background images that are all 10px high and 181px wide. Inside of an element 181px wide and variable height, I am placing image 1 at the top of element, image2 at the bottom of the element, and image 3 repeats all the way down. Here is the code:

```
#sidemenu li a.currentpage {
    background:     url(images/sm-urhere_top.png) no-repeat center top,
            url(images/sm-urhere_bottom.png) no-repeat center bottom,
            url(images/sm-urhere_bg.png) repeat-y center top;
    }
```

sm-urhere_top.png and sm-urhere_bottom.png are both a little blurred (I kind of like the effect), but images/sm-urhere_bg.png is crisp. In fact, if I replace sm-urhere_top.png or sm-urhere_bottom.png with sm-urhere_bg.png, it is only blurry when not repeated. I made all three images using the same program, they are the same size, and I saved them each with the same compression. What gives?

Edit: It only seems to happen in Chrome, not in Firefox. Is there a reason that chrome would blur images only if they are not repeated? Is there a way to blurr repeated images in chrome?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the HTML of the element:

```
`<ul class="normal">`
`    <li><a href="#" title="This is the description." class="currentpage">Current Page</a></li>`
`</ul>`
```

Okay, I think I figured it out - kind of. The top and bottom images have rounded corners. For some reason, chrome sees the detail in the corners and blurs the image to make it look nicer. To solve, I added a little discrete detail to the middle image, and voila.

Still don't understand why chrome would blur the same image if it is not repeated. But it is what it is.

Comment: can you post some HTML as well? and my be a http://jsfiddle.net/ would be great too

Comment: we need a working example to experience the same problem as you, and then we can look into it. Where's `#sidemenu` in your HTML? can you use jsfiddle, show us a working example with the problem and send it here ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with jsfiddle. I'm trying it out, but I don't see a way to upload photos. Is there a way to? Or should I just add my code with no photos?

Comment: no problem with the photos, we can put our own to test it :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kCBDH/2/  Hope that works.

Comment: you could host the images on imgur.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it made me crazy for 1 hour ...
google pointed me only to effects .. not to bugs  :)

So for future reference it appears it was only when Zoomed in some png backgrounds (like corners for menus or buttons) get blurred ugly, even if on 110%.

I don't see the point in this but that was the issue for me.